# Exclusão da Tag Fluent

Tags: debate

Recentemente realizei um esforço de edição na tag [fluent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent) para retirar a ambiguidade que existe na tag entre três tópicos disjuntos entre si:

- Fluent API: Recurso para enunciação de configuração de entidades do Entity Framework (criada uma nova tag, [fluent-api](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-api));
- Fluent NHibernate: Recurso para enunciação de configuração de entidades do NHibernate (criada uma nova tag, [fluent-nhibernate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-nhibernate));
- Fluent Interface: Padrão de implementação de uma interface orientada a objetos onde cada método devolve o próprio objeto chamador.

Fluent Interface não existe como tag, e agora há apenas uma pergunta que usa essa tag que trata justamente disso. O que acham de renomear a tag [fluent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent) para [fluent-interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-interface)?

Comment: Concordo, até pq a tag `fluent` estava muito aberta, agora com essa nova classificação ficaria melhor direcionado

Comment: faz mais sentido ser específico